# Splitting string and getting maxlegth of longest string

Tags: javascript, scripting, logic

I want to `split` a string value according to `<br/>`

An example string:

```
""* Minimum 3 digits allowed<br/>" * Maximum 9 digits & 2 precisions allowed<br/>"
```

in the above case there will be two values in array

```
1. * Minimum 3 digits allowed
2. * Maximum 9 digits & 2 precisions allowed
```

And need to find the length of the string from the array (which is already splitted) which have the maximum length within the array.

So that answer will be 40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = '* Minimum 3 digits allowed<br/>* Maximum 9 digits & 2 precisions allowed<br/>';

var spltArr = str.split("<br/>");
var longStr = null;
var maxLen = -1;
for(var i = 0; i < spltArr.length; i++ ){
    if( longStr === null ){
        longStr =  spltArr[i];
        maxLen =  spltArr[i].length;  
    }
    if( spltArr[i].length > maxLen ){
        longStr =  spltArr[i];
        maxLen =  spltArr[i].length;
    }
}
console.log("Max len: ", maxLen, "String:", longStr);
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yWDvK/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "* Minimum 3 digits allowed<br/> * Maximum 9 digits & 2 precisions allowed<br/>";
var arr = str.split('<br/>');

var longest = 0;
var longest_string = '';

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i].length > longest) {
        longest = arr[i].length;
        longest_string = arr[i];
    }
}

alert("Longest string is: " + longest_string + " (char count: " + longest + ")");
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, I've just woken up :) I'll modify it for JS quickly. Sorry about that..

Comment: Fix your answer to javascript or remove it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "* Minimum 3 digits allowed<br/>* Maximum 9 digits & 2 precisions allowed<br/>";
var lines = str.split('<br/>');
var longest = '';

for(i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {
    if(lines[i].length > longest.length) {
        longest = lines[i];
    }
}
alert('Longest string:' + longest + ' (Length: ' + longest.length + ')');
```